# Conditional Styling and Binding

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, styling

In Angular 2 I am binding a dollar value like this inside a TABLE TD.

```
<td>
  {{eachOutlet.dollarValue}}
</td>
```

This dollarValue will be less than 0 or equal to 0 or greater than 0.
When it is less than zero it should show up in "Red" color.
When it is zero, nothing should show up. Just blank text.
When it is greater than zero, it should use thousands separator and show the number.

How can I apply such conditional styling using Angular 2 binding?
Is it even possible to do it ?

Comment: You can create a formatting pipe. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```ts
<td>
  <span 
    *ngIf="eachOutlet.dollarValue != 0"
    [style.color]="eachOutlet.dollarValue < 0 ? 'red' : null">
      {{eachOutlet.dollarValue | number:'1.0-2'}}
  </span>
</td>
```

You can also create a directive that does the styling (except the `number` pipe) to make it easier to reuse over different elements.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PdOPvi2wrBuDFvA7bb5t?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect ! Working exactly as I was expecting. Thank you. :)

Comment: Thanks - glad to hear :) Just a hint. On SO it's common to upvote instead of thanks ;-) If the answer solves your problem you can also make an answer the accepted answer.

Comment: Though Adam says it's working exactly as expected, I don't think the following expectation was met: "When it is greater than zero, it should use thousands separator and show the number." You always format the number (even if it is a negative one). Maybe the formatting should be done via  a custom pipe to eliminate the formatting of negative numbers.

Comment: The format parameter can be an expression like `eachOutlet.dollarValue | number:eachOutlet.dollarValue <= 0 ? '1.0-2' : '1.0-0'`

Answer (score 6):

Another option for more than one style property:

---

- In Template:

---

```
<div style="word-break: break-all;" [ngStyle]="{ 'top': getTop() +'px', 'left': getLeft() +'px' }"> </div>
```

---

- And in the Component:

---

```
getTop(){
    return (this.topValueShowComment> 0)? this.topValueShowComment : 0;
}

getLeft(){
    return (this.leftValueShowComment> 0)? this.leftValueShowComment : 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect and clean answer if you have many conditional variables to check. For example: "If X is true then check for Y and Z".

Answer (score 3):

We can do like this.

```
<div class="responsive-standalone--Overlay" (click)="mobileRMenu()" [style.display]="rMenu ? 'block' :'none'"></div>
```