# How to assign background color to <p-column> depends upon field values in angular4

Tags: angular, primeng

I created one primeNG table. In that I want to assign background color depends upon the field value. If field value is between 50% to 60% I want to assign red color. If field value is between 60% to 70% I want to assign yellow color. If field value is above I want to assign green color. How I do it?
Code for primeNG table is below

```
<p-dataTable [value]="facility" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true"  [globalFilter]="gb" #dt [pageLinks]="4" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]" >
     <p-column  [style]="{'width':'5%'}" field="action" header=""></p-column>
     <p-column field="Goal" header="Goal"  [sortable]="true"  ></p-column>
    <p-column field="day1" header="8/1" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day2" header="8/2" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day3" header="8/3" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day4" header="8/4" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day5" header="8/5" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day6" header="8/6" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day7" header="8/7" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day8" header="8/8" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day9" header="8/9" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day10" header="8/10" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day11" header="8/11" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day12" header="8/12" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day13" header="8/13" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day14" header="8/14" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day15" header="8/15" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day16" header="8/16" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day17" header="8/17" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day18" header="8/18" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day19" header="8/19" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day20" header="8/20" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     <p-column field="day21" header="8/21" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/41305481

Answer (score 1):

Use ngStyle from [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle#how-to-use). This ***example***, needs to be adapted to your situation, but is very similar to your case:

**TypeScript**

```
changeColor(value){
    return value>30 ?'red' : 'green' // please adapt to your need
}
```

**HTML:**
.....

```
 <p-column field="Col3" header="Column 3" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width': '200px'}">
    <ng-template let-data="rowData" pTemplate="body">
      <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': changeColor(data['Col3'])}">
        {{data['Col3']}}
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
```

.....

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/M1Njgm2eIfP1dEmgv5H8?p=preview)**

Comment: For above example background color is set for particular div present inside the template but I want to set background color to whole cell. Is it possible?

Comment: See the updated demo, please. To style cells you have to define a div inside the column and define the ng-template.