# I have "ERROR in Internal Error: Unexpected interpolation" error when I run npm start in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I have this error when I run `npm start`:

```
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.16 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 722 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 518 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 711 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 882 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 340 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-02-15T13:20:57.999Z - Hash: ddcf910bd445ac9ea9a0 - Time: 8343ms

ERROR in Internal Error: Unexpected interpolation
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Comment: Are there any errors when you open dev tools in your browser? If so, can you add them to your question.

Comment: same here after upgrading to v9 and there is no any detail. It says only Error in error

Comment: Same here. No idea what the problem is. If I run the app with `ng serve` I get - `Cannot GET /`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also happened to me, and I got around it by updating updating my tsconfig. This allowed me to see the html errors that were preventing the build from completing. Here's what I modified

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
```

**UPDATE**
After fixing all the obvious html errors the error still persisted, and after extensive research I found this [git issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33575) 
The problem was in my html, where I had this line:

```
style="background-image: {{currentuser.profile.photoURL}}"
```

This is generally not a good practice, and removing this line immediately cleared the error. If anyone is facing the same problem I recommend checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305404/conditional-styling-and-binding).

In my case I just changed the above line to

```
[style.background-image]="currentuser.profile.photoURL"
```

Worked like a charm